# Not activating child routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular version: 1.3.17

UI-Router version: 0.2.15

```
angular.module('demoApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('admin', {
        url: '/admin',
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl'
      })
      .state('admin.category', {
        url: '/category',
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/category/category.html',
        controller: 'CategoryCtrl'
      })
})
```

For some reason the child `admin.category` state never activates when I visit `/admin/category`. I can see no reason why it should not work, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: since you aren't using html5mode did you put a hash in the path?

Comment: No I didn't put any hash to the path. I just only managed to find the problem. I didn't put any `<ui-view />` tag in the parent state.

Comment: that would do it..but so will no hash

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Are you saying even if I don't put `<ui-view />` tag to the parent state the child view would still load?

Comment: no...need that but the url needs `#/` in it also  like `example.com/#/admin/`. Also set an `otherwise` for default route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For child states to be active, ui-router expects that the parent state's template will contain a `<ui-view/>` tag that will load the child state. I forgot to put the tag in the template hence the child controller was never getting activated.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your admin state should be abstract like this:

```
  .state({
    name: 'admin',
    templateUrl: 'app/admin/admin.html',
    controller: 'AdminCtrl',
    abstract: true
  })
```

Comment: Not really. For activating a child state the parent state don't have to be abstract.